# simulate clicks without user interactivity every x seconds

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have 5 divs every div call H4.
I create this by javascript to get the result and it works but now I need it to do this automatically in sequence without user interactivity to be like auto slider, for example, caption1 should click first and show caption1content after 8 seconds caption 2 clicks and show captoin2content and so on how can I do this by javascript.

JS:

```
$("#caption1").on('click', function() {
               $("#caption1content").fadeIn();
               $("#caption2content,#caption3content,#caption4content,#caption5content").fadeOut();
            });
            $("#caption2").on('click', function() {
               $("#caption2content").fadeIn();
               $("#caption1content,#caption3content,#caption4content,#caption5content").fadeOut();
            });
            $("#caption3").on('click', function() {
               $("#caption3content").fadeIn();
               $("#caption1content,#caption2content,#caption4content,#caption5content").fadeOut();
            });
            $("#caption4").on('click', function() {
               $("#caption4content").fadeIn();
               $("#caption1content,#caption2content,#caption3content,#caption5content").fadeOut();
            });
            $("#caption5").on('click', function() {
               $("#caption5content").fadeIn();
               $("#caption1content,#caption2content,#caption3content,#caption4content").fadeOut();
            });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="caption">
    <h4 id="caption1content" class="ccntnt">text1</h4>
    <h4 id="caption2content" class="ccntnt">text2</h4>
    <h4 id="caption3content" class="ccntnt">text3</h4>
    <h4 id="caption4content" class="ccntnt">text4</h4>
    <h4 id="caption5content" class="ccntnt">text5</h4>
</div>
<div id="captionbtns">
    <div id="caption1">text1</div>
    <div id="caption2">text2</div>
    <div id="caption3">text3</div>
    <div id="caption4">text4</div>
    <div id="caption5">text5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it is pretty simple you can use setInterval and you can do it like this not the perfect way but working.

it will click after every 8 seconds it will only loop through it once and further you can use a if condition to reset the count if you want to run it again and again;

```
let count = 1;

setInterval(function(){

  $(`#caption${count}`).click();
  count++;
},8000);
```

Comment: well, you are pretty awesome, thank you so much, it works.
may I ask you to give me the way how to do it with if condition to make it run again and again?

Comment: without user activity... this form of interaction, jQuery call "trigger"  $(`#caption${count}`).trigger('click')